# Alert policy "ALL conditions are met on matching resources" does not match filters or groupByFields

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm willing to create an alert thanks to GCP Stackdriver to create an alert for Pub/Sub such as "IF a subscription has more than XXX awaiting messages (unacked) for a topic AND the consumption rate of that consumer on that topic is near 0, then trigger an alert".

I'm more used to Prometheus where I can simply rely on the labels to kinda join timeseries, but I'm wondering how to do that with Stackdriver.

At first, I thought about using 2 conditions with the "policy violates when ALL conditions are met on matching resources", but I'm wondering if that "matching resources" is the same behavior as in Prometheus.

Here is the alert I thought about, but it seems to trigger even when the 2 conditions are not fully fulfilled:

```
{
  "combiner": "AND_WITH_MATCHING_RESOURCE",
  "conditions": [
    {
      "conditionThreshold": {
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "alignmentPeriod": "60s",
            "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_SUM",
            "groupByFields": [
              "metadata.system_labels.topic_id",
              "resource.label.subscription_id"
            ],
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_RATE"
          }
        ],
        "comparison": "COMPARISON_LT",
        "duration": "300s",
        "filter": "metric.type=\"pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/ack_message_count\" resource.type=\"pubsub_subscription\" resource.label.\"project_id\"=\"pl-service-prod-lm-fr\"",
        "thresholdValue": 1,
        "trigger": {
          "count": 1
        }
      },
      "displayName": "Ack message count"
    },
    {
      "conditionThreshold": {
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "alignmentPeriod": "60s",
            "crossSeriesReducer": "REDUCE_SUM",
            "groupByFields": [
              "metadata.system_labels.topic_id",
              "resource.label.subscription_id"
            ],
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_MEAN"
          }
        ],
        "comparison": "COMPARISON_GT",
        "duration": "300s",
        "filter": "metric.type=\"pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages\" resource.type=\"pubsub_subscription\" resource.label.\"project_id\"=\"pl-service-prod-lm-fr\"",
        "trigger": {
          "count": 1
        }
      },
      "displayName": "Unacked messages"
    }
  ],
  "displayName": "Pub/Sub is not consumed",
  "enabled": true,
  "incidentStrategy": {}
}
```